# ERROR 1726 (HY000) at line 35: Storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support system tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to transfer table 'mysql.user' from mysql 8.0.19 to mysql 14.14. However, it causes error `ERROR 1726 (HY000) at line 35: Storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support system tables.` There's nothing in logs, so I have no idea how to resolve this. Does anybody know how to address the issue?

Comment: There is no mysql 14.14?

Comment: There is no such thing as MySQL 14.14.

Comment: also, there is no "TRANSFER TABLE" statement in MySQL ...   (and in general, it is very difficult to resolve a problem without knowing how to reproduce the problem.) If I needed to reproduce the contents of the mysql.user table from one instance to another, I would typically use the SHOW GRANTS FOR user@host , or if I wanted DML INSERT statements, I would use mysqldump to get those. But it's not at all clear what we are trying to accomplish, or how we are going about it.  I think the "error" happened way before the error message appeared.

Comment: sorry, it's 5.7.29-32, i.e. I'm transferring the table from 8.0.19 to a lower version, and this error pops up. 

I also see that in both cases InnoDB is the default engine, so I have no idea what can be the problem.

to reproduce the issue, just try to dump a table from Mysql 8.0.19 and import it in Mysql 5.7.29-32.